# Shared category table and PHP OOP approach

Tags: php, design-patterns, mysqli

I have the following database table for storing different types of categories (lookup codes). Here different categories share the same database table and are distinguished by cattype column.

```
catid|catname|catvalue|cattype
-----+-------+--------+-------
1     Adult   100      Age
2     Child   200      Age
3     Black   150      Hair
4     Blond   220      Hair
```

Now I map this DB table to base DAO class which extends basic DAO class DataBase (which provides db connection, etc ($db)):

```
abstract class Category extends DataBase
{
  public catid;
  public catname;
  public catvalue;

  protected function getAll($cattype)
  {
    $sql="SELECT catid,catname,catvalue FROM categories WHERE cattype='$cattype'";
    $rst=$this->db->query($sql);
    while($row=$rst->fetch_assoc())
    {
      $Category=new Category()
      foreach($row as $key=>$val) $Category->$key=$val; //fill variables from row
      $Categories[]=$Category;
    }
    return $Categories;
  }
}
```

Each particular category has its own class:

```
// Returns age categories from 'categoris' table

class AgeCategory extends Category
{
  public function getAll()
  {
    return parent::getAll('Age');
  }
  public function getSomething() {};
}


// Returns hair categories from 'categoris' table

class HairCategory extends Category
{
  public function getAll()
  {
    return parent::getAll('Hair');
  }
  public function getSomething() {};
}
```

The problem here is that function getAll() from child class returns the array of parent objects of type Category. When I loop through all child objects like:

```
$AgeCategory=new $AgeCategory()
$AgeCategories=$AgeCategory->getAll();

foreach($AgeCategories as $AgeCategory)
{
  $cat=$AgeCategory->getSomething() //IT DOES NOT WORK!!!
}
```

I cannot call getSomething() function because it is child's object function since $AgeCategory->getAll() returns age cagetories of type Category not AgeCategory! How can avoid this problem? I want the array of AgeCategory classes back.

OK, one solution is Factory pattern where I would send parameter to parent class and it would instantiate appropriate class for my array. Is there a better (simpler) solution for this problem? Maybe completely different approach.

Comment: Indeed a decorator pattern as Phpdna stated. a factory pattern is creational and would not apply as you need to return a composite data type of categories at runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can use a decorator pattern.  It is common approach when you have lots of categories.